# Javascript: Change Div size on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var idTab5 = document.getElementById("idTab5");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function showwMore() {
    button.style.display="none";
    idTab5.style="overflow:hidden;display:block;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;";
        button2.style.display="block";

}

function showwLess() {
    button2.style.display="none";
    idTab5.style="overflow:hidden;height:250px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;";
    button.style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

and this is the other code:

```
{if $product->description|count_characters:true > 350 }
        {* full description *}
        <div id="idTab5"  style="overflow:hidden;height:250px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">{$product->description}</div>
        <input id="button" type="button" style="margin-top:5px;font-size:12px;color:white; width:120px;background:#4e3248;border:none;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" value="Mostrar +" onclick="showwMore()"> 
        <input id="button2" type="button" style="margin-top:5px;display:none;font-size:12px;color:white; width:120px;background:#4e3248;border:none;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" value="Mostrar -" onclick="showwLess()">
    {else}
        <div id="idTab5"  style="overflow:hidden;height:250px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;">{$product->description}</div>
    {/if}
```

now its seems fine to me, but onclick, the div isnt growing, any idea why is this happening? ive checked the code many times cant find out why it isnt working, did i miss something???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For use multiple styles by javascript you can use `setAttribute()` like

should be

```
idTab5.setAttribute("style", "overflow:hidden;display:block;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;");
```

**Or**

you can use `cssText` property to use css as string on element

```
idTab5.style.cssText = "overflow:hidden;display:block;height:100%;font-size:40px;line-height:14px;";
```

instead of

```
idTab5.style="overflow:hidden;display:block;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:14px;";
```

Comment: you've got to be kidding me, in the begginning my code was working, suddenly it stopped working.. and now changing just what you suggested is working again... jeez, thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement a little css animation so the div doesnt get bigger that fast?

Comment: It http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768242/trying-to-use-basic-javascript-to-animate-a-div-and-make-it-bigger-but-have-it-g gives some context to you.

Comment: THANKS. sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="idTab5"  style="height:250px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px; border:1px solid black;"></div>
        <input id="button" type="button" style="margin-top:5px;font-size:12px;color:black; width:120px;background:#4e3248;border:none;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" value="Mostrar +" onclick="showwMore()"> 
        <input id="button2" type="button" style="display:none;margin-top:5px;display:block;font-size:12px;color:white; width:120px;background:#4e3248;border:none;height:30px;border-radius:5px;" value="Mostrar -" onclick="showwLess()">
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var idTab5 = document.getElementById("idTab5");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");

function showwMore() {
    button.style.display="none";
    idTab5.style="display:block;height:100%;font-size:12px;line-height:14px; border:1px solid black;";
        button2.style.display="block";

}

function showwLess() {
    button2.style.display="none";
    idTab5.style="height:250px;font-size:12px;line-height:14px; border:1px solid black;";
    button.style.display="block";
}
```

see **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/satishJS/2CTdD/)**

Comment: This does not work, you can't use multiple styles as you did. `idTab5.style="height:250px;font-size:12px;`