# How do I change the div size by clicking multiple button?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the div size when someone clicks the corresponding button. For example, clicking the small button will make the div width 30%, and clicking the medium button will make the div width 50%.

I found this [Javascript: Change Div size on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110434/javascript-change-div-size-on-button-click), but it's not working for me because I don't know his HTML structure, and he is using ID instead of class.

Below is my code. Please help me:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.Button_Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Content_Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Button_Container">
  <button class=">FULL" onclick="myFunction">FULL</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="myFunction">Medium</button>
  <button class="Small" onclick="myFunction">Small</button>
</div>

<div class="Content_Container"></div>
```

Comment: where is implementation of myFunction

Comment: Sorry, I'm learning JavaScript and not quite familiar with it. So I left it to be blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(width){

var all = document.getElementsByClassName('Content_Container');
for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
  all[i].style.width = width;
}
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
}

.Button_Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Medium {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

.Content_Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Button_Container">
  <button class=">FULL" onclick="myFunction('100%')">FULL</button>
  <button class="Medium" onclick="myFunction('70%')">Medium</button>
  <button class="Small" onclick="myFunction('50%')">Small</button>
</div>

<div class="Content_Container"></div>
```

Comment: May I know the use-case for class instead of ID? Because I have multiple div and I need to target it by class instead of ID.

Comment: ok, I have changed my code for class. may it helpful